# I want to connect to a SQL server on another domain using Windows authentication while there is no trust between domains

Tags: c#, sql

The situation is as follows:

- We have a web service on a Windows 2008 R2 server (not in  a domain) called IISServer1
- We have a Hardware VPN Connection (site to site) to a Windows domain of one of our clients.
- Our client has a SQL server called SQLServer1
- We can connect to SQLServer1 from our IISServer1 using the command prompt with `runas /User:domain\user /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"` and entering the password when asked.

Now what we want is to enable the web service on our IISServer1 to connect to SQLServer1  using system.data.sqlclient in C#.

Is this possible? If so, could you provide an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a simple connection string using "SQLServer1" as the host?  If that isn't working, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal SQL Authentication connection string. Once you have network level access, it don't matter anymore whichever authentication you use. If it MUST be Windows Authentication, just make sure the SQLServer1 have security defined for domain\user in the SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately we cannot use the normal SQL Authentication connection string. We must use the Windows Authentication. The error we receive from the SQL server is "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

Comment: Can you provide the code that attempt the connection?  and have the Windows user been created in the SQL server?